# Find bounds of norm difference of circular shift

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, fourier-transform

Given $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that the norm is fixed $\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert^2 = n\times \rho$.

Define circular shift operator $\mathrm{circshift}([x_0, x_1, ..., x_n-1], \tau) = [x_{n-\tau}, x_{n-\tau +1}, ..., x_{n-1}, x_0, ..., x_{n-\tau-1}]$ with $\tau \in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$

> I want to find the bounds of $\left\Vert \mathbf{x} -
>  \mathrm{circshift(}\mathbf{x},\tau)\right\Vert^2$ by $\tau$, i.e. $G$ and $H$ that
>
> $$\left\Vert \mathbf{x} -
>  \mathrm{circshift(}\mathbf{x},\tau)\right\Vert^2 < G \quad\textrm{ for
>  } 1 \leq \tau \leq n-1$$
>
> and $$\left\Vert \mathbf{x} -
>  \mathrm{circshift(}\mathbf{x},\tau)\right\Vert^2 > H \quad\textrm{ for
>  } 1 \leq \tau \leq n-1$$

and I expect that the bounds depend on the norm $\rho$ and the length $n$.

Call $\mathbf{X}$ the DFT of $\mathbf{x}$.

Thus by [Parseval theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_physics),
$$\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} |X(k)|^2 = P$$

and

$$\left\Vert \mathbf{x} - \mathrm{circshift(}\mathbf{x},\tau)\right\Vert^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} |X(k)|^2 |1 - e^{j2\pi\frac{k}{m}\tau}|^2$$

The first thing that cross my mind is that $|1 - e^{j2\pi\frac{k}{m}\tau}| < 2$, thus $\left\Vert \mathbf{x} - \mathrm{circshift(}\mathbf{x},\tau)\right\Vert^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} |X(k)|^2 |1 - e^{j2\pi\frac{k}{m}\tau}|^2 < 4\times\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} |X(k)|^2 = 4n\rho$ which seems quite loose.

Any hints or inequalites that I can use to derive $G$ and $H$ would be appreciated.

Comment: In this generality, I don't see a bound that's substantially better than using triangle inequality, $\|x\| + \|\operatorname{circshift} (x,\tau)\|$. Consider what happens when $x$ is a basis vector like $(1, 0, \dots, 0)$; any shift results in an entirely different direction of the vector.

Comment: @if.... yes, it seems by using triangle inequality, I end up with the same upper bound $4 n \rho$ that I got by using Fourier transform and upper bounding the exp term.